# Dynamic links block

Tags: blocks

I want to make a block with dynamic links. An example path would be http://example/node/7/addreview
The number 7 will change depending on what node it's viewing. So if it's viewing node 14 then it should be http://example/node/14/addreview. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable module `PHP Filter` it is part of drupal core and disabled by default

Add a new (custom) block (/admin/build/block/add)

Add following code in the body

```
<?php
    if(arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)){
        print l('Add review', 'node/'. arg(1) . '/addreview');
    }
?>
```

Set `Input Format` type to `PHP Code`

Save your block with appropriate visibility conditions

Associate your block to some region beside main content area.